# PhpStorm Shopware plugin shortcut 'swconfig' does NOT work

Tags: plugins, phpstorm, shortcut, shopware

In PhpStorm I've installed the plugin "Shopware", and it works for most of the cases.

But when I tried to use the Live Template shortcut `swconfig` in PhpStorm for calling up some default configurations of Shopware, this shortcut did NOT exist/work at all.

What's the problem? Should I do some other configurations to enable this shortcut in the plugin?

I hope someone can help me in this.

Comment: Not Shopware user. But do you see Shopware's Live Templates in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live Templates` ? if it's not there then contact Shopware plugin author asking for reasons.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the settings do not help me further.

Comment: I'm sorry .. but your response does not help much in finding out what you have tried and what you have there (I cannot see your settings, so may only guess). Based on that -- please contact plugin author and he may give better advise as he knows better how his plugin should work: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-shopware-plugin/issues

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to download the `settings.jar` file from the ["Shopware Developer Training Basic"](https://www.udemy.com/developer-training-basic/learn/v4/content) Udemy course.
   [image: udemy shopware settings.jar phpstorm]
2. In Phpstorm open the Menu *File -> Import Settings* and select the downloaded  settings.jar

Comment: if you are using sync with your account you need to stop the sync (with last settings) import the jar file then sync from local to account